# Not getting data from req.body while updating prodct data in mern project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have been trying to update product on my ecommerce website, when update button is clicked no errors are showing, its showing the old data and no change in the mongodb database.
also tried in postman, it shows no errors ,shows the old data as response.

when i print "req.body.name" in the controller code, it shows undefined in the console.

somebody please suggest a change in the code

controller

````
import Category from "../models/categoryModel.js"
import multer from "multer";
import productModel from "../models/productModel.js";
export const updateproducts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("name "+req.body.name)
        const product = await productModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                
                name: req.body.name,
                description: req.body.description,
                images: req.body.images,
                mrp: req.body.mrp,
                category: req.body.category,
                InStock: req.body.InStock,
                rating: req.body.rating,
                numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
                isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
            },
            { new: true }
        );

        if (!product) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found or cannot be updated.' });
        }

        res.json({ message: 'Product updated successfully', updatedProduct: product });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
}; ```

Front end

    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AdminSidebar from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminSidebar';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import AdminHeader from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminheader';
import "./Admindashboard.css";


const UpdateProduct = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [mrp, setMrp] = useState("");
    const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
    const params = useParams();
    const [InStock, setInStock] = useState("");
    const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
    const [pid, setId] = useState("");
    const [DeletedImages, setDeletedImages] = useState([]);


    const getSingleProduct = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/getsingle-product/${params.id}`);
            console.log(data);

            setName(data.product.name);
            setId(data.product._id);
            setDescription(data.product.description);
            setSelectedImages(data.product.images);
            setMrp(data.product.mrp);
            setCategory(data.product.category);
            setInStock(data.product.InStock);
            if (data.success) {
                console.log("hai");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleProduct(params.id);
        console.log(params.id);
        //eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    const getAllCategory = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/category/get-category");
            if (data.success) {
                setCategories(data.category);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCategory();
    }, []);


    //update product function
    const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const productData = new FormData();
            productData.append("name", name);
            productData.append("description", description);
            for (let img of selectedImages) {
                productData.append("images", img);
            }
            productData.append("mrp", mrp);
            productData.append("category", category);
            productData.append("InStock", InStock);

            const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, productData);
            console.log(productData);

            if (data?.success) {
                toast.error(data?.message);
            } else {
                toast.success("Product Created Successfully");
                navigate("/dashboard/manage.vision/admin/products");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            toast.error("something went wrong");
        }
    };

    const onSelectFile = (event) => {
        const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
        const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);

        setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(selectedFilesArray));
        console.log(selectedImages);

        // FOR BUG IN CHROME
        event.target.value = "";
    };

    const deleteHandler = (file) => {
        setDeletedImages((prevDeletedImages) => [...prevDeletedImages, file]);
        const remainingImages = selectedImages.filter((f) => f !== file);
        setSelectedImages(remainingImages);
    };

    return (
        <body className='body'>
            <div className="container-fluid ">
                <div className="row">
                    <AdminHeader />
                    <AdminSidebar />
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <div>
                            <button>Cancel</button><button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
                            <div className="prgrid">
                                <div className='upimg'>
                                    <h4 className="prhead">Product Images<hr /></h4>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="file" id='upload' accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/webp" onChange={onSelectFile} multiple />
                                        <label className="label" for="upload"><h3>Upload +</h3></label>
                                        <div className="images">
                                            {selectedImages &&
                                                selectedImages.map((image, index) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <div key={image} className="image">
                                                            <img src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${image}`} alt="upload" className="primg" />
                                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="prdele" onClick={() => deleteHandler(image)} />
                                                            <p className="imgno">{index + 1}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    );
                                                })}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="prcat">
                                    <h4 className="prhead">Product Category</h4><hr />
                                    <Form.Select className="catsel" onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
                                        {categories?.map((c) => (
                                            <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                                                {c.name}
                                            </option>
                                        ))}
                                    </Form.Select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="prinfo">
                                <h4 className="prhead">Product Info</h4><hr />
                                <Form.Label htmlFor="prname" className="prlab">Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    id="prname"
                                    value={name}
                                    placeholder="Product Name"
                                    required
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                />
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                                    <Form.Label className="prlab">Description</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} className="prdes" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </div>
                            <div className="prprice">
                                <h4 className="prhead">Product Pricing</h4><hr />
                                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Maximum Retail Price</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="number"
                                    id="prpice"
                                    value={mrp}
                                    onChange={(e) => setMrp(e.target.value)}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="prprice">
                                <h4 className="prhead">Inventory Status</h4><hr />
                                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Status</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className="stat" value={InStock} onChange={(e) => setInStock(e.target.value)}>
                                    <option >Update Status</option>
                                    <option value="0">In Stock</option>
                                    <option value="1">Out Of Stock</option>
                                </Form.Select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    );
};

export default UpdateProduct;
````

Comment: when you console log just req.body what are you getting? is it empty or is there data?

also make sure your express is using the json middleware: app.use(express.json());

Comment: shows idefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue here,
You are passing your data in formData while requesting to update of the data.
You have to pass your data in `json object` to access it through `req.body`.

try to pass this below object in your `axios` request.

```js
const productData = {name,description, ...otherProps}
const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, productData);
```

I know you have to use formData to pass images but first, you should try it without images using `json`.

**OR**

the issue can be in your entry file of the backend which can be `index.js` or `app.js`.
Make sure you've added the code to access the json from the body which is given below.

```js
app.use(express.json());       
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Also, try to console `req.body` only and check if it is `undefined`.